# ImportError: Could not import settings 'bootcamp.settings'

Tags: django, python-2.7

ImportError:
 Could not import settings 'bootcamp.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named unipath

plz tell me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The settings file attempts to import [Unipath](https://github.com/mikeorr/Unipath), which is not installed. You just need to install it:

```
pip install Unipath
```